# Reading Javascript array as key value pairs using python xpath

Tags: python, xpath

How can I read the below Javascript array as key value pairs using python xpath? OUtput in python would be ['id', '359521','name', 'HO1 mini-briefs HO1' etc]

Possibly in 1 go to get a python list element where I can access the data

Help appreciated

## JAVASCRIPT IN HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    var wcIsGtm = false;
    var productImpressions = [];
    var promoImpressions = [];
    var wcGuaTrackerName = '';
    var wcGuaGlobalTrackerName = 'allstores.';
    var wcGuaGlobalTrackerEnabled = '0';

    var referralExclusionList = [];

    if(document.referrer) {
        for(excludedDomain in referralExclusionList) {
            if(document.referrer.indexOf(excludedDomain) != -1) {
                document.referrer = '';
            }
        }
    }


        (function(w,e,b,c,oo,ki,ng){w['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=oo;w[oo]=w[oo]||function(){
        (w[oo].q=w[oo].q||[]).push(arguments)},w[oo].l=1*new Date();ki=e.createElement(b),
        ng=e.getElementsByTagName(b)[0];ki.async=1;ki.src=c;ng.parentNode.insertBefore(ki,ng)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-19354276-10', 'auto');
ga('require', 'ec');
ga('set', '&cu', 'EUR');



             var productDetail = {
                 'id': '359521',
                 'name': 'HO1 mini-briefs HO1',
                 'category': 'Collection HOM Basics/Slips',
                 'brand': '',
                 'price': '10.4',
                 'variant': ''
             };
             ga('ec:addProduct', productDetail);
             ga('ec:setAction', 'detail');


ga('send', 'pageview');


</script>


<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:title" content="HO1 mini-briefs HO1" />
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
```

## another example would be

```
    var AWACP_CONFIG = {
        mageVersion: '1.9.3.1',
        useProgress : 1,
        popupForAllProducts : 0,
        addProductConfirmationEnabled : 1,
        removeProductConfirmationEnabled : 1,
        dialogsVAlign: 'center',
        cartAnimation: 'opacity',
        addProductCounterBeginFrom : 0,
        removeProductCounterBeginFrom : 0,


        hasFileOption : false    };
```

## Possible code logic

```
# todo make more robust to read JS data 
var_to_find = 'productDetail'
pattern = re.compile(r"var {var_to_find}} ?= ?({.*?});", re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
xpath_string = "//script[contains(text(), 'var %s')]/text()" % var_to_find
js_data = response.xpath(xpath_string)[0].rstrip()
js_data = js_data.re(pattern)[0]
json_data = json.loads(js_data)
print(json_data)

The idea is to 
1. find JS variable based on some input var (we know the var name)
2. it finds the data inside {.*}
3. it strips alle spaces, newlines, comments and only keeps "var1":"data","var3":"data","var3":"data",
4. then split on , to obtain key values pairs
5. then split on : to set key and values in list, excluding " or '

Step 3 is the most complet because it needs to be robust to deal with any kind of formatting
```

Comment: Not sure what xpath has to do with it. What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: Key value pairs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do something like the below. Note that xpath isn't going to work here and regex is problematic. So the cleanest way to do it, I believe, is with string manipulation and a dictionary.

For the first:

```
arr = """your first html example"
splt_str = 'var productDetail = {'
trg = arr.split(splt_str)[1].split('}')[0].split(',')
stf = {}
for t in trg:
    entry = t.strip().replace("'","").split(':')
    stf[entry[0]]= entry[1]
for k, v in stf.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Output:

```
id  4002021
name  Tommy string
category  Collection Brand Basics
brand  
price  8.31
variant
```

For the second, change the first two lines to:

```
arr = """your second html example"
splt_str = 'var AWACP_CONFIG = {'
```

Output:

```
mageVersion  1.9.3.1
useProgress   1
popupForAllProducts   0
addProductConfirmationEnabled   1
removeProductConfirmationEnabled   1
dialogsVAlign  center
cartAnimation  opacity
addProductCounterBeginFrom   0
removeProductCounterBeginFrom   0
hasFileOption   false
```

Comment: Cool ;) Only uncertaintyis that code might sometimesbe a little different. Multiple newlines, spaces before and after data. And `var AWACP_CONFIG = {` can also be `AWACP_CONFIG = {`or `var   AWACP_CONFIG =    {`

Comment: @snh_nl I can see the difference between the "normal" `var AWACP_CONFIG = {` and the first example in your comment - that example has no `var`; but I can't see the difference between it and the second example - they seem the same to me.